# Creating skin like Adobe Kuler for an Adobe Air application

Tags: air, adobe, skinning

How can I create skins for Adobe Air 1.5 application, like [Adobe Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Degrafa](http://degrafa.org) or you can use .swf as skins, use .css or Adobe extensions for design [this site](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/skins_styles.html) explains how do that

Let me know how it goes..
bye